# Javascript - Preencher segunda coluna dinamicamente de tabela html

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia pessoal
Estou a ter problemas com tabelas dinamicas usando javascript, sou novata e nao sei ao certo o que fazer. A questao e' a seguinte: tenho uma tabela criada em html com duas colunas, a primeira ja foi preenchida usando html mas a segunda coluna deve ser preenchida dinamicamente, tentei fazer isso mas os dados aparecem somente na primeira linha da segunda coluna e nao preenche todas as linhas dessa coluna.. Me ajudem

Comment: Zaira, poderia postar o código da tabela?

Comment: Posta o código que você tem até o momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que sua tabela tem um TBODY:

```
<table id="minhaTabela">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Valor Fixo</td>
            <td>Valor Dinâmico</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Um</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dois</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Três</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Você poderia, para cada uma das linhas do TBODY, acessar a segunda célula da linha e definir o conteúdo dessa célula:

```
// Acessa a tabela:
var minhaTabela = document.getElementById('minhaTabela');

// Acessa o primeiro tbody da tabela:
var tBody = minhaTabela.tBodies[0];

// Acessa cada linha da tabela:
for (i = 0; i < tBody.rows.length; i++) {

    // Define o valor (i+1) da segunda célula (cells[1]) de cada linha (rows[i]) da tabela:
    tBody.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = i+1;
}
```

**Veja funcionando**

```js
// Acessa a tabela:
var minhaTabela = document.getElementById('minhaTabela');

// Acessa o primeiro tbody da tabela:
var tBody = minhaTabela.tBodies[0];

// Acessa cada linha da tabela:
for (i = 0; i < tBody.rows.length; i++) {

    // Define o valor (i+1) da segunda célula (cells[1]) de cada linha (rows[i]) da tabela:
    tBody.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = i+1;
}
```

```html
<table id="minhaTabela">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Valor Fixo</td>
            <td>Valor Dinâmico</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Um</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dois</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Três</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Valeu pela sugestao.. Deu muito certo, consegui preencher a tabela como pretendia